# GEE APP Error "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-maps-api, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to make my first small app for water extent as learning GEE.
But I am facing the error of not able to read the property.
ERROR display msg is `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`.

My code is

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/ashwin8199/wetlands74");
// display major reservoir
Map.addLayer(table,{},'reservoirs');
Map.centerObject(table,4);

////////////////////////////
// panel widgets
// app title
var header = ui.Label('Water Extent Time Series', 
    {fontSize: '25px', fontWeight: 'bold', color: '4A997E'});
// app summary
var text = ui.Label(
  'This toolbox maps wetland water extent in the India.' +
  'Use the tools  to explore.',
    {fontSize: '15px'});
// create panel
var panel = ui.Panel({
  widgets:[header, text],//Adds header and text
  style:{width:'33%',position:'middle-right'}});
  
// add panel to root of gui
ui.root.insert(1,panel);

// label for data used
var datause = ui.Panel(ui.Label('Satellite Data use'));

var L5=ui.Checkbox('Landsat 5').setValue(false);L5.onChange(function(checked){});
var L7=ui.Checkbox('Landsat 7').setValue(false);L7.onChange(function(checked){});
var L8=ui.Checkbox('Landsat 8').setValue(true);L8.onChange(function(checked){});

var dataPanel = ui.Panel({
          widgets: [L5,L7,L8],
          layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'),
        });
panel.add(datause)
      .add(dataPanel);

// panel for data date range
var Daterange = ui.Panel(ui.Label('Enter date range'));

var startyear=ui.Textbox({
  placeholder: 'Enter Start Year...',
  // onChange: function(value){startyear.setValue(value);return(value)},
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal'}
});

var endyear=ui.Textbox({
  placeholder: 'Enter End Year...',
  // onChange: function(value){endyear.setValue(value);return(value)},
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal'}
});

var yearPanel = ui.Panel({
          widgets: [startyear, endyear],
          layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'),
        });
        
var startmonth=ui.Textbox({
  placeholder: 'Enter Start Month...',
  // onChange: function(value){startmonth.setValue(value);return(value)},
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal'}
});

var endmonth=ui.Textbox({
  placeholder: 'Enter End Month...',
  // onChange: function(value){endmonth.setValue(value);return(value)},
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal'}
});

var monthPanel = ui.Panel({
          widgets: [startmonth, endmonth],
          layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'),
        });
        
panel.add(Daterange)
      .add(yearPanel)
      .add(monthPanel);

var Wetlands = ui.Panel(ui.Label('Select the wetland from the drop menu'));

var wetlandSelect = ui.Select({
  items:['Supa','Bhadra','Pulicat'],
  placeholder:'Choose Wetland',
  // onChange: function(value){wetlandSelect.setValue(value);return(value)},
  style: {position:'top-right'}
});

panel.add(Wetlands)
.add(wetlandSelect);

var Run = ui.Button(({label: 'Plot extent'}));
panel.add(Run);

Run.onClick(mainProg);



/////////////////////////////////
// Global variables
var first_year, last_year, first_month, last_month, geometry, wetland,startDate, endDate
;
///////////////////////////////////
// mane code
function applyfilter(){
function aoi(){
  wetland=wetlandSelect.getValue();
  var geometry=table.filterMetadata('Name','equals',wetland);
}
setAreaOfInterest();

first_year = startyear.getValue();
last_year = endyear.getValue();
first_month = startmonth.getValue();
last_month = endmonth.getValue();
  var startDate = ee.Date(first_year+'-'+first_month+'-'+'01');
  var endDate = ee.Date(last_year+'-'+last_month+'-'+'28');
  
}

var water = function(image) {
  var mask = image.select(['pixel_qa']).eq(324).or(image.select(['pixel_qa']).eq(388));
                  return img.updateMask(mask);
};

var mainProg=function(){
  applyfilter();
  print(startDate);
  print(endDate);
var dataset=ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,endDate))
.filterBounds(geometry)
.select(['pixel_qa']);
dataset=dataset.map(water);
print(geometry);
Map.centerObject(geometry,11);
var hist = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(dataset.select('pixel_qa'),geometry,ee.Reducer.sum(),30);
panel.add(hist);
};
```

Comment: can you share your assets such that your example actually works?

Comment: I recommend not using the global variables. To debug this better, try including all of the `applyfilter` operations directly inside of the `mainProg` function.

Comment: @Jobbo90 the link for the code..  https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/?scriptPath=users%2Fashwin8199%2FTest1%3Awater_area_app

Comment: @JustinBraaten . I did try that, no help. the code link is https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/?scriptPath=users%2Fashwin8199%2FTest1%3Awater_area_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem (the one that's causing that specific error) is that mainProg is only being defined after it's been bound to the Run button.  Change the way it's declared (don't use var) so it can be found and bound properly.

```
function mainProj() { ... }
```

But you have numerous other issues, including that the `startDate` and `endDate` variables are re-declared in the `applyfilter` function, so the globals are never seen/used/set (remove the var's on them), and the `setAreaOfInterest` function doesn't exist.

There doesn't seem to be much use in the functions with no arguments.
Even though it's not a good programming practice, I recommend that you do everything inside the mainProg function without using other functions, until you get the basics working.  The aliasing of variable names, etc, looks like it's getting in your way.  Once you've got it working, then you can modularize your code more.